# On mac 10.9, symbols are not getting exported from dylib (qt 5.3) project

Tags: c++, macos, qt5, xcode5.1

I am able to build qt 5 project (.pro) on mac 10.9 successfully on xcode 5 using Run script. But when I try to see the symbols using: `nm -a libmyproject.dylib`, then it shows nothing.

I exported my class using:

```
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) myclass
{
  public: 
    void mymethod()
    {
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Your method is inline. The compiler will not output its code if no one in your library is using it, and even if it does, there's no reason to export the symbol. This has nothing to do with visibility.

Comment: @n.m, No, even though I declared mymethod as static method and defined in cpp file. Still it is not getting exported from dylib. Am i doing anything wrong. Do we need to add any thing in pro file or xcode 5 settings?

Comment: And If i build my project with qt 4 then all the symbols(methods) are getting exported. To build it in xcode i am using following commands as a run script in build phase:  qmake pathtoprofile -r -spec macx-g++ CONFIG+=${CONFIGURATION}

Comment: Do you get **any** symbols in your library?